# three column layout equal height

Tags: html

How to make three column layout having equal height using only css and html (no js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use [faux column background technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

You can also try giving three divs massive bottom paddings with massive bottom margins with a container with `overflow: hidden`. It doesn't play nice with inline anchors though.

Comment: @abdullah Nope, sorry. If you don't have to support < IE8, use `display: table-cell`.

Comment: previous one was better.coz, i have to support ie7+

Answer (score 0):

```
<html><body>
```

`<div>`

```
<div style="float:left;height: 33.33%;width:10%;background-color:red">zdfsfs</div>
<div style="float:left;height: 33.33%;width:10%;background-color:blue">zgfsgsgfsgf</div>
<div style="float:left;height: 33.33%;width:10%;background-color:cyan">zvgzcxgvxz</div>
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: But what happen when content increase randomly

Comment: I have given small width.you can increase width.and still content is larger then content will come out div and this solution will not work.I will try to find its solution and let you know if I got it.

Comment: thanks. but i think solution given by 'alex' that i accepted is more better. try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {display : table-cell;}
```

This Could Be Another Solution To The Problem!
For More Information, Please See This Link: [Is there a disadvantage of using `display:table-cell`on divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307934/is-there-a-disadvantage-of-using-displaytable-cellon-divs)