# HTML List element : Sharing the parent width into equal parts

Tags: html, css

I have a parent `<ol>` and couple of `<li>` items in that.

```
<ol style='width=800px;display :block;float:left;'>
   <li style='display :block;float:left;'> Item 1  </li>
   <li style='display :block;float:left;'>  Item 2 </li>
   <li style='display :block;float:left;'>  Item 3 </li>
   <li style='display :block;float:left;'>  Item 4 </li> 
</ol>
```

Is there any way my list item can be arranged in a way where it will equally divide the parent width (800px), and each item will have the same amount of width? I.e. each `<li>` will take 200px width.

I don’t want to hardcode the value. Is there any style attribute which will do that?

I dont want to hardocode the width like 20 % or something because the list items are dynamically added.it may be 4  or 5 or 6 sometimes

Comment: `style=width=800px;display :block;float:left;'` <-- You might wanna fix that too

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/QzYAr/

- For details on `display: table-cell`: [Is there a disadvantage of using `display:table-cell`on divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307934/is-there-a-disadvantage-of-using-displaytable-cellon-divs/6307988#6307988)
- [`table-layout: fixed` ensures](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) equal width `li` elements.

**CSS:**

```css
ol {
    width: 400px;
    /*width: 800px;*/

    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed; /* the magic dust that ensures equal width */
    background: #ccc
}
ol > li {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    text-align: center
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Perhaps useful for others: table-layout: fixed; worked for me only after setting a width, e.g. width: 100%. The above post contains a width but I just wanted to emphasize that it was a necessary condition to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're asking for. It required jQuery though.

http://jsfiddle.net/sKPLQ/3/

CSS:

```
ul {
    width: 800px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

JS:

```
var evenWidth = $(".list").width()/$(".list li").size();
$(".list li").css("width", evenWidth);
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimalistic design.  It will produce  responsive equal distance cells

```
<style>
   div { border:1px solid red; width:400px; height:400px; }
   ul { width:100%; height:50px; list-style: none; margin:0; padding:0; text-align: center; }
   li { background-color:green; color:White; width:1%; position:relative; display:table-cell; border:solid 1px white; }
</style>

<div>
   <ul>
      <li>CELL 1</li>
      <li>CELL 2</li>
      <li>CELL 3</li>
      <li>CELL 4</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The magic is `width:1%; position:relative; display:table-cell;`

Answer (score 1):

As Renesis pointed out, I think table cells is the only option, unless you're scripting it. Although you can use table-cell in CSS.

```
#menu {display: table-row;}
#menu li {display: table-cell;}
```

..which will simulate the behaviour. Note that in IE it will, as usual, cause problems in the lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

> **Please note:** The original poster edited their question to exclude percent after I posted this answer.

Yes, you simply need to figure out the percent that each will use.  In this case, **20%**.

Also, you have some slight problems with your HTML (missing quote and `width=` instead of the correct `width:`).

```
<style>
    ol { width:800px;display :block;float:left; }
    li { border:1px solid black; display :block;float:left; width:20%; }
</style>
<ol>
   <li> Item 1  </li>
   <li>  Item 2 </li>
   <li>  Item 3 </li>
   <li>  Item 4 </li> 
</ol>
```

---

**Update:**

While you can get away without defining pixels by using a percentage, there is no way with block elements to get away without defining *any* width value (and width values are only valid as a unit or a percentage).

Not that I'm suggesting you use tables, but table cells are the only elements in HTML that sort of behave like what you are asking for.

Comment: the li items will be dynamic in number.So cant hardcode like 20 %.