# Equally share width of <ul> amongst <li> children

Tags: html, css, html-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML List element : Sharing the parent width into equal parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310632/html-list-element-sharing-the-parent-width-into-equal-parts)

I have a `div` that contains a `ul` element:

```
<div style="width: 800px">
    <ul style="width: 100%">
        <li>...</li>
        ....
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I automatically give the `li` elements equal space throughout the `ul`?

Comment: you mean to make them horizontally and span across each end?

Comment: how many `<li>` do you have? and are they placed horizontally?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6310632/681807

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to span a list horizontally, this should suffice:

```
HTML
<div>
    <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

CSS
#list li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

In this case, I adjust the padding to span the items evenly as I would like them to be.

Answer (score -2):

I would use this css:

```
 #list li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    ***width:100px;***
}
```

Comment: This only works when there are exactly 8 `li`'s. I think OP is looking for a more flexible solution.