# CSS text overflow ellipsis for wrapper with multiple horizontal elements

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper element with a variable width (it must depend on the browser current width).

Inside that wrapper there could be 1, 2 or 3 span elements. 
The length of the text on each `spans` is unknown.

This is the behavior expected, but for this example I was forced to define a width for each `span` of 30% (define a width of 30% to use the `text-overflow:ellipsis`), But, and I can not assign a fixed width in this elements since I font know how many spans will be.

[image]

Is there a way to get this behavior without specify a width for each element and without using java script?

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle ?

Comment: Basically, here is your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6311029/27862 Just add `white-space: pre;` to the `li` and set `width: 100%` on the `ol`

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML List element : Sharing the parent width into equal parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310632/html-list-element-sharing-the-parent-width-into-equal-parts)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a width otherwize every element will have a width at 100% :/

It's not a problem to not specify a width when there is only 1 element

Answer (score 0):

you can count how many spans were rendered then divide the entire width with the number of spans...the result would be the width of each span... then you can do something like

```
 $('.spans').css('width', computedwidth);
```