# Can I use Display:Tables properties for layout

Tags: html, css

I am aware that table should not be used for layout and only for tabular data. I see that there is Table and other like Table-row... attr for display in CSS. Can I use these for layout. I feel hard to get it work using div and float.

Thanks

Comment: A code example is not needed for something as simply explained as "Can I use these values for this property for this purpose?". It isn't as if there is a complex interaction of stuff which is not behaving as expected.

Comment: "Can I use `display: table` / `display: table-row` / etc for layout?"

Comment: @srijan — Because writing a better answer than Matt Fellows' would involve spending more time on research then I care to invest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a disadvantage of using `display:table-cell`on divs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307934/is-there-a-disadvantage-of-using-displaytable-cellon-divs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - this is absolutely fine to do - providing your target browsers support it.  Some do not.

Comment: Yes, the value `table` (and `table-row`, `table-cell`, `inline-table` (and quite a few others https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/CSS/display ) of the CSS2 property `display` are fine to use. It's only design. The problem with HTML tables is that other elements are better suited (even `div`), that they can cause problems with linearization in screen readers (and now smartphones), etc