# Three columns layout - set left and right div's heigth according to center div

Tags: html, css, floating

- I need to make a three columns css layout (without setting the height and width).
- The left and right div height need to set automatically according to the center div (center div height depends on its content)

I tried with position, height 100%, overflow, but something wrong, so I cleared my code and so for now here I'm standing:

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
   background-color: green;
   float: left;
}

.right {
   background-color: yellow;
   float: left;
}

.center {
   background-color: red;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"> < left</div>
    <div class="center"> 
       <p>Holisticly underwhelm process-centric architectures via functionalized quality vectors. Collaboratively transform turnkey total linkage rather than value-added technologies.</p>
     <p>Holisticly underwhelm process-centric architectures via functionalized quality vectors. Collaboratively transform turnkey total linkage rather than value-added technologies.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">right > </div>
</div>
```

thank you

Comment: This question has been asked since the dawn of time. There are however several answer to this question already on stackoverflow. I suspect this question will get flagged to close as a duplicate question.

Comment: I just search stackoverflow and found 102 pages for questions relating to Three columns layout. Check them out. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Three+columns+layout

Comment: possible duplicate of [three column layout equal height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576500/three-column-layout-equal-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to `display:flex` is `display:table`

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  display: table;
  width: 100%; /*optional*/
}
.container > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left {
  background-color: green;
  width: 75px; /*optional*/
}
.right {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 75px; /*optional*/
  text-align:right;
}
.center {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">&lt; left</div>
  <div class="center">
    <p>Holisticly underwhelm process-centric architectures via functionalized quality vectors. Collaboratively transform turnkey total linkage rather than value-added technologies.</p>
    <p>Holisticly underwhelm process-centric architectures via functionalized quality vectors. Collaboratively transform turnkey total linkage rather than value-added technologies.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">right &gt;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
.container
   Display: inline-flex;
   Flex-direction: row;
If you want to center 
  Justify-content: center.